# html5 canvas use javgascript to change opacity of rectangle due to mouse distance from rectange

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, opacity

Hi I would like to draw a rectangle on a canvas, but I would like the opacity of that rectangle to be higher the closer the mouse is to the rectangle. I know its probably very simple but I have been struggling with getting this to work. i am currently not using any libraries in my project so pure JavaScript would be preferable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you should do is google some things. DONT BE LAZY!!! Find out these things 1 by 1: How to make a rectangle, how to set the opacity of this rectangle, how to find the absolute position of an element on your screen(in your case the top left corner of the canvas -> if the rectangle is not directly placed in the top left corner you should add the amount of pixels on the x and y axis.), after that find out mouseposition on the screen. Paste all these things together and youre good to go.

Comment: If you have any code written add it to the question, then we can try to help you with it. What are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide code to adjust, here is a textual outline:

- listen for mousemove events
- calculate mouse position in mousemove event handler
- (in calculating be sure to adjust for the offset of the canvas because the coordinates you get from the event listener are relative to the web page, not the canvas itself)
- Use the "distance formula to get distance from the mouse to the center of the rectangle (or edge of rectangle)
- Make a design decision about what distance number will result in what rectangle opacity
- use context.clearRect to clear the rectangle from the canvas
- canvas opacity is set using globalAlpha: set context.globalAlpha to your desired opacity.
- redraw the rectangle
- repeat, repeat, repeat!